# Protobuf json_format changes datatype from int to float

Tags: python, json, protocol-buffers

I have a python dict like so:

```py
{'class_name': 'InputLayer',
 'config': {'batch_input_shape': (None, 32),
  'dtype': 'float32',
  'sparse': False,
  'ragged': False,
  'name': 'input_5'}}
```

When I try to convert it to a protobuf message using the `json_format` method then it changes the `int` datatype of `config.batch_input_shape` `32` to `float` `32.0`.

The code used for conversion (`layer_config` is the above `dict`):

```py
import json
from google.protobuf import json_format
from google.protobuf import struct_pb2 as struct

json_format.Parse(json.dumps(layer_config), struct.Struct())
```

**Is there any way to avoid this type conversion from `int` to `float` ?**

I also tried to convert using the `update` method, like so:

```py
s = Struct()
s.update(layer_config)
```

but then also it converts the types.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the initial research this is not something that can be addresses relatively easily due to how numbers are converted in Python

[protobufs/well_known_types.py](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/python/google/protobuf/internal/well_known_types.py)  has a method `_SetStructValue` that does the type conversion and where we are handling numbers we are type checking for both `float` and an `int`.

```
def _SetStructValue(struct_value, value):
  if value is None:
    struct_value.null_value = 0
  elif isinstance(value, bool):
    # Note: this check must come before the number check because in Python
    # True and False are also considered numbers.
    struct_value.bool_value = value
  elif isinstance(value, str):
    struct_value.string_value = value
  elif isinstance(value, (int, float)):
    struct_value.number_value = value
  elif isinstance(value, (dict, Struct)):
    struct_value.struct_value.Clear()
    struct_value.struct_value.update(value)
  elif isinstance(value, (list, ListValue)):
    struct_value.list_value.Clear()
    struct_value.list_value.extend(value)
  else:
    raise ValueError('Unexpected type')
```

One possible solution here is that we traverse the payload object graph and perform necessary type conversions to know types as necessary.